# Integration in Python Midpoint Calculation

Tags: python, math, numerical-integration

I came across this integral approximation function in a book. It seems efficient and provides accurate results with fewer `subintervals ((n)`).

```py
def approximate_integral(a, b, n, f):
    delta_x = (b - a) / n
    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        midpoint = 0.5 * (2 * a + delta_x * (2 * i - 1))
        total_sum += f(midpoint)
    return total_sum * delta_x
```

Since the above midpoint calculation isn't obvious, I searched for the mathematical formula and implemented it. However, it approaches the correct answer only when I use far more intervals than the implementation found in the book.

```
midpoint = a + 2 * dx + i * dx
```

```py
def approximate_integral(a, b, n, f):
    dx = (b - a) / n
    tot_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        midpoint = a + (dx / 2) + (i * dx)
        tot_sum += f(midpoint)
    return tot_sum * dx
```

Please explain the efficiency and the differences between this formula and the one I used:

```
midpoint = 0.5 * (2 * a + delta_x * (2 * i - 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the midpoint in my function accounted for an extra interval. After I reduced the ith iteration by 1, it worked as the formula in the book.

```
midpoint = a + (dx/2) + ((i-1) * dx)
```